# Как мне получить список всех приложений(запущенных и нет) на компьютере с возможностью их последующего запуска?

Tags: c#

Для поиска приложений использовал ManagementObjectSearcher:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
var test = mos.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList();
```

и RegistryKey:

```
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
{
    var test = key.GetSubKeyNames()
        .Select(a => {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(a))
            {
                return subkey.GetValue("DisplayName");
            }
        })
    .Cast<String>()
    .ToList();
}
```

В обоих случаях удается получить лишь имя приложения, но не полный путь для создания процесса.

Comment: Многие приложения не регистрируются в реестре, поэтому информации о них там нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полный путь всех программ на записаны в реестре Windows. В этом можно убедится если открыт реестр и посмотрет записи. 
[image: Реестр Windows]

Однако путь болшинство из них можно получит слейдующим образом

```
 using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
        {
            foreach (var k in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(k))
                {
                    var path = subkey.GetValue("InstallLocation");
                    if (path == null)
                        path = subkey.GetValue("InstallSource");
                    Console.WriteLine(path);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Оказывается и так можно

```
 using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store"))
        {
            foreach (var k in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Вроде нашел недостающее в Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store"
Выглидит так RegistryKey key = ...;
key.GetValueNames()

Comment: дополни пожалуйста и я приму как ответ.

Comment: @лалалалала а Вы уверены что "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store" существует, на моем реестре нет токого пути

Comment: возможно ты ищешь на LocalMachinе, а не на CurrentUser.

Comment: @лалалалала исправил кажется